# Automatic Deployment role in sccm2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, software-update, wsus, sccm

I'm configuring some Automatic deployment rule in SCCM2012R2 .After specifying product updates ,the wizard noticed that just first 1000 update will deployed .So I divided updates in two rules .now I don't have any problem .But the question is that How about the future,after a while maybe two month ,less or more, the number of Updates will get increased,and will become more than 1000 items ,because I've selected option "Add to an existing Software update Group".Should I change it to option "Create New software Update Group" during Automatic deployment wizard ?Or there are other some other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be a good idea to create a catch up Software Update Group (SUG) by year (or something close like 2014 and pre-2014) since SUGs cannot exceed 1,000 updates when deployed and then create new SUGs monthly with ADR by setting the search criteria for Date Released or Revised in the last 1 month. Other search criteria that might be helpful is setting Required to >=1 so that you are only getting updates that are needed by your environment as well as setting Superseded to No.

Comment: How does one do what you describe exactly?